# vagrant with virtualbox on wsl VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND

Tags: vagrant, windows-10, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I try to run vagrant from wsl :

**Windows 10 Pro Version 1703 Build 15063.540**

**Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS**

**vagrant version : 1.9.7**

**Virtualbox version : 5.1.26r117224**

add to my bachrc

```
export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"
```

and i have added the virtualbox to path in windows

[image]

on run **vagrant up** i got this error

> Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: RawFile#0 failed to create the raw
>   output file
>   /mnt/d/Projects/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/Fabric/devenv/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
>   (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)

if i try to start the vm from Virtualbox directly

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine hyperledger.
>
> RawFile#0 failed to create the raw output file
>   /mnt/d/Projects/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/Fabric/devenv/ubuntu-xenial-16.04-cloudimg-console.log
>   (VERR_PATH_NOT_FOUND).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005) Component: ConsoleWrap Interface:
>   IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have found the solution

it to add

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize [ "modifyvm", :id, "--uartmode1", "disconnected" ]
end
```

to the vagrant file

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8604

However, you may also do this via the VirtualBox UI as shown here, i.e. the "disconnected" as shown will accomplish the same thing.  `vb.customize` - the `.customize` will not work for some vagrant versions.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted...this did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: I see the snippet as a temporal solution.
As @mmarchini explains [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8604#issuecomment-303259512) the problem is because of the path of the log file is not properly calculated by Vagrant? or by the code present in the Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 7):

I resolved same issue by **turning off** the **serial port in the virtualbox configuration**.

If you need the serial port, you can leave it enabled but change the log file path to match your filesystem

Comment: I can confirm that after disabling the serial port, it is now working for me.

Comment: Can you tell where to update the log file path?